# Play with Netty frameworks

Tags: rest, playframework, netty

We are getting the new requirement for a web based application which uses RESTful Web services. we are planning to use Play with Netty. Where to find the best documents and video materials to start the application from scratch.

Any tools are available to generate the skeleton of the project like maven archetype.

Answer (score 0):

Play comes bundled with netty already. You can learn more about it at 
http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.1/Home

Answer (score 0):

Don't go into mavenizing a Play application unless you have a good Maven level.

Paly! comes with all the stuff needed by the developpers.